# Create custom python inspection in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, inspection

Is there a way to create a custom inspection for Python code in Intellij? I need to blacklist a Python function so it throws a warning whenever somebody imports it or types it in.

Comment: Following up to this a year later, I created a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050352/disallow-strftime-in-a-code-base) that is making better progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only have experience with JavaScript plugins for IntelliJ, but it should work the same for Python.

You can write a plugin that provides an inspection. There's a learning curve of course, but once you get the environment setup it's pretty smooth.

First, you will need to check out [the plugin development page from JetBrains](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment). 
Here are the steps I would take:

- Download the [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition source](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983225). It's not required, but searching through the source is useful.
- Try to follow the [basic plugin tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development). It's a Java plugin, but it's a good start. For Python you may need to add a dependency on a plugin jar.
- Specific for your case, [read up on PsiElements](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Architectural+Overview#IntelliJIDEAArchitecturalOverview-PsiElements). Using PsiElements is how you navigate and modify the source code.
- For practical examples, [browse the plugin repository](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea) and look for open source plugins. I found them the most helpful when developing my own plugin.

When you finish that, you can start writing your plugin. For an inspection, there are a few classes you will be concerned about:

- `LocalInspectionTool` is the actual inspection that will search a file and flag problems. You extend this class
- `InspectionToolProvider` is the interface you implement to determine if a file will run a particular inspection.
- `ProblemDescriptor` is the class that will represent your error message. You can optionally provide a fix to remove the elements in question.

You will get a PsiFile that represents your source file. Using this, you can search for the function in question and flag it as an error.

One last fantastic resource is the [plugin development forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development). Usually one of the developers will respond if someone else doesn't answer your question, so don't hesitate to post there.