# Disallow `strftime` in a code base

Tags: python, git, intellij-idea, strftime, unit-testing

I want to make sure that no developer on our codebase can ever check in code that uses `strftime`. It's a super useful method, but since it [can't be used on dates before 1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263956/use-datetime-strftime-on-years-before-1900-require-year-1900), it's a constant source of bugs that we only discover once code goes live.

I've thought of a few ways to make it so it can't be used:

1. Create an inspection in Intellij that throws an error when `strftime` is encountered.

   (This seems OK, but creating Intellij inspections is a big deal.)
2. Create a unittest that greps any changes that are currently in the code and makes sure `strftime` hasn't snuck back in again.

   (Seems hacky and adds a dependency for some git tool.)
3. Create a git hook of some kind that explodes when strftime appears in a commit.

   (Looked into this but git hooks must be manually symlinked which kind of defeats the point -- kind of.)
4. Subclass the `datetime` module with an implementation that raises a `NotImplemented` error if `strftime` is ever used.

   (But people could still import the regular datetime module.)
5. Just train myself and everybody else that it's the devil.

   (But this hasn't worked so far.)

I feel like this is probably something that has a standard way of being resolved. Any suggestions?

Comment: number 3 is the most reasonable that I can think of that ensures that no code will ever be committed with strftime (some people will hate you, though, when their commits are rejected)

Comment: Yeah, seems like this or PyLint are the best solutions. I'd love to monkeypatch `datetime` to remove `strftime`, but I can't do that without breaking all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use [pylint](http://docs.pylint.org/) to `lint` your code. Specifically, the [basic_checker](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker) could be used to warn when forbidden functions are used (the default is for map, filter, etc).

You could tie this as a `pre-commit` hook in `git` to ensure that the offending function is not used.

Comment: I like this, but I don't think we're using pylint unfortunately. We've found the Intellij inspections to be preferable.

Comment: Pylint has some resources for [IDE integration](http://docs.pylint.org/ide-integration.html). If you use Pycharm, [here](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-616) is a post that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of (4).  I'm not necessarily sure if it's the *best* way to accomplish this, but it will work.  Put this in your top-level `__init__.py`, which runs before everything else:

```
import datetime

class datetime(datetime.datetime):
    # Override strftime, and make any other changes here

datetime.datetime = datetime
```

This will monkey-patch the built-in `datetime.datetime` implementation with your hacked version.  It's important to realize this will *also* break any of your dependencies which may be using `datetime.strftime()`, so test before deploying.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this will work, but you may be able to abuse Python's warnings system into working around the dependency problem.  Start by changing your implementation to this:

```
import warnings

class datetime(datetime.datetime):
    def strftime(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn('strftime is deprecated', DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
        return super(datetime, self).strftime(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will issue a deprecation warning whenever the function is called.  Deprecation warnings are ignored by default, so this will not create false positives for Django.  You can then install a warning filter like so:

```
warnings.filterwarnings('error', 'strftime is deprecated', DeprecationWarning,
                        r'your_package(\..+)?') # regex matching your package
```

In theory, this filter should only raise exceptions on code within `your_package`.  In practice, I have not tested it, so it might not raise any exceptions whatsoever.

Comment: I loved this concept and I tried this out but it turns out that since we use Django for this project, nuking `strftime` in this way breaks the hell out of Django. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/mlissner/deda9a7ec0726704a8e5) that I put in `__init__.py` of one of our main Django apps, in case you see something I don't.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed your comment re dependencies. Bummer.

Comment: @mlissner: I thought of another way and added it to my answer.  I don't know if it will work, but I think it probably should.

Comment: Alas, this too fails. Django code calls `isinstance(value, datetime.datetime)`, which used to return True and now returns False. I'm decided that this causes too much breakage and, though it feels elegant, just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to `del time.strftime` in some startup code.

It will be able to check it in but it will always throw `AttributeError` on access.

Comment: I decided I liked @Kevin's answer better because it allowed me to throw a `NotImplemented` error. Sadly though, it looks like either of these techniques will break dependencies for the project.

Comment: Can't you just, like, *replace* `datetime.datetime` with your compatible yet better implementation? Removing the problem in the first place.

Comment: Yet another way is to make a private copy of the module for your code (e.g. make an `argparse.Namespace` out of its `__dict__`) or [hook the import system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imputil.html).

Answer (score 1):

Introduce them to the `wx.DateTime` class from [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) - once they have got used to it you would need a gun to get them to use strftime - it is a static class so can be used without the rest of the [wx tool chain](http://wxpython.org/) and you do not need a `wx.App` before using it.

Some [features](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_datetime.html):

- Wide range: the range of supported dates goes from about **4714 B.C**. to some **480 million** years in the future.
- Precision: not using floating point calculations anywhere ensures that the date calculations don't suffer from rounding errors.
- Many features: not only all usual calculations with dates are supported, but also more exotic week and year day calculations, work day testing, standard astronomical functions, conversion to and from strings in either strict or free format.
- Efficiency: objects of wxDateTime are small (8 bytes) and working with them is fast
- DST aware in some timezones.

Comment: Long term I think we'll do this. There's also the [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) library, but I haven't evaluated it yet. Short term, I think we just need a blocking mechanism of some kind.

Comment: I have always found that if you block something then people work at getting around the block either technically or politically - if you can give them an alternative that is actually easier as well as better they are more likely to follow along.

Comment: The other advantage of some kind of structural block is that if dependencies are introduced we'll catch uses of `strftime` in them too without having to vendor all of them.